# Functions for translating a vector from one coordinate system to another

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, vector, coordinate-transformation

I have a vector $\vec{H}$ with components in Cartesian coordinate system $(x,y,z)$: $\vec{H}=(0,0,H)$. I would like to obtain coordinate of this vector in Spherical coordinate system $(r,\theta,\phi)$.

Are there in Mathematica functions for translating a vector from one coordinate system to another? Particular, in my case from Cartesian coordinate system to Spherical coordinate system.

Comment: There is `ToSphericalCoordinates[{x,y,z}] `. Unfortunately for your vector  the spherical coordinate system is singular.  Nonetheless one can rotate a vector before transformation, make a transform and rotate back, e.g. `ToSphericalCoordinates[{0, H, 0}]` works well.

Comment: Useful [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70493/how-do-i-convert-a-vector-field-in-cartesian-coordinates-to-spherical-coordinate) on MathSE.

Comment: @Artes, thanks! But I don't understand , why this function doesn't work correctly in my case?

Comment: You should try and see what happens.  $\phi$ will not be determined uniquely in other words this transformation isn't bijective.

Comment: How about `TransformedField[ 
 "Cartesian" -> "Spherical", {0, 0, 
  H}, {x, y, z} -> {r, θ, φ} ]` ?

Comment: @Syed, thanks, It's work!